# PHP Count Up Variable Names

Tags: php

I need the following repeated multiple times:

```
$eventobj = new ZCiCalNode("VEVENT", $icalobj->curnode);
$eventobj->addNode(new ZCiCalDataNode("SUMMARY:" . $title));
...
```

So to output:

```
$eventobj1 = new ZCiCalNode("VEVENT", $icalobj->curnode);
$eventobj1->addNode(new ZCiCalDataNode("SUMMARY:" . $title));

$eventobj2 = new ZCiCalNode("VEVENT", $icalobj->curnode);
$eventobj2->addNode(new ZCiCalDataNode("SUMMARY:" . $title));

$eventobj3 = new ZCiCalNode("VEVENT", $icalobj->curnode);
$eventobj3->addNode(new ZCiCalDataNode("SUMMARY:" . $title));
...
```

How can i do that in a loop? I tried this, but it did not work:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++){
$eventobj.$i = new ZCiCalNode("VEVENT", $icalobj->curnode);
$eventobj.$i->addNode(new ZCiCalDataNode("SUMMARY:" . $title));
}
```

Comment: Probably use an array of objects `$eventobj[$i]`

Comment: Also, do you really need to do this `new ZCiCalDataNode("SUMMARY:" . $title)` every time or just once and store it in a var?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++) {
  $eventobj[$i] = new ZCiCalNode("VEVENT", $icalobj->curnode);
  $eventobj[$i]->addNode(new ZCiCalDataNode("SUMMARY:" . $title));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work as well:

```
$eventobj = new ZCiCalNode("VEVENT", $icalobj->curnode);
$eventobj->addNode(new ZCiCalDataNode("SUMMARY:" . $title));
$eventobj = array_fill(1, 99, $eventobj);
```